# Copy the schema from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, schema, pyspark-schema

I have a Spark data frame (`df1`) with a particular schema, and I have another dataframe with the same columns, but different schema. I know how to do it column by column, but since I have a large set of columns, it would be quite lengthy. To keep the schema consistent across dataframes, I was wondering if I could be able to apply one schema to another data frame or creating a function that do the job.

Here is an example:

```py
df1
# root
#  |-- A: date (nullable = true)
#  |-- B: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- C: string (nullable = true)

df2
# root
#  |-- A: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- B: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- C: string (nullable = true)`
```

I want to copy apply the schema of `df1` to `df2`.

I tried this approach for one column. Given that I have a large number of columns, it would be quite a lengthy way to do it.

```py
df2 = df2.withColumn("B", df2["B"].cast('int'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its possible dynamically with **`dataframe.schema.fields`**

`df2.select(*[(col(x.name).cast(x.dataType)) for x in df1.schema.fields])`

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('2022-02-02',2,'a')],['A','B','C']).withColumn("A",to_date(col("A")))
print("df1 Schema")
df1.printSchema()
#df1 Schema
#root
# |-- A: date (nullable = true)
# |-- B: long (nullable = true)
# |-- C: string (nullable = true)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('2022-02-02','2','a')],['A','B','C'])
print("df2 Schema")
df2.printSchema()
#df2 Schema
#root
# |-- A: string (nullable = true)
# |-- B: string (nullable = true)
# |-- C: string (nullable = true)
#

#casting the df2 columns by getting df1 schema using select clause
df3 = df2.select(*[(col(x.name).cast(x.dataType)) for x in df1.schema.fields])
df3.show(10,False)
print("df3 Schema")
df3.printSchema()

#+----------+---+---+
#|A         |B  |C  |
#+----------+---+---+
#|2022-02-02|2  |a  |
#+----------+---+---+

#df3 Schema
#root
# |-- A: date (nullable = true)
# |-- B: long (nullable = true)
# |-- C: string (nullable = true)
```

In this example I have **df1** defined with `Integer,date,long types`.

**`df2`** is defined with `string` type.

**`df3`** is defined by using `df2` as source data and attached `df1 schema`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

**Input Dataframes**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

from datetime import datetime

data1 = [("2022-01-01", 1, "A"),
         ("2022-01-02", 2, "B"),
         ("2022-01-03", 3, "C")
        ]

data1 = [(datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d"), b, c) for date_str, b, c in data1]

schema1 = StructType([StructField("A", DateType(), True),
                      StructField("B", IntegerType(), True),
                      StructField("C", StringType(), True)
                     ]
                    )

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, schema=schema1)

df1.printSchema()

data2 = [("2022-01-04", "4", "D"),
         ("2022-01-05", "5", "E"),
         ("2022-01-06", "6", "F")
        ]
schema2 = StructType([StructField("A", StringType(), True),
                      StructField("B", StringType(), True),
                      StructField("C", StringType(), True)
                     ]
                    )
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema=schema2)

df2.printSchema()
```

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=df2.rdd,schema=df1.schema)
df2.printSchema()

root
 |-- A: date (nullable = true)
 |-- B: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- C: string (nullable = true)
```

Alternatively, you create a method you need a more generic solution -

```
def apply_schema(df1, df2):
    schema1 = df1.schema
    
    schema2 = df2.schema
    
    data_types = {field.name: field.dataType for field in schema1.fields}
    
    for field in schema2.fields:
        column_name = field.name
        
        if column_name in data_types:
            column_type = data_types[column_name]
            df2 = df2.withColumn(column_name, df2[column_name].cast(column_type))
    
    return df2
```

And use this method to impose the schema of df1 over df2 -

```
df2 = apply_schema(df1, df2)

print("Schema of df1:")
df1.printSchema()

print("Schema of df2:")
df2.printSchema()

df2.show()

Schema of df1:
root
 |-- A: date (nullable = true)
 |-- B: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- C: string (nullable = true)

Schema of df2:
root
 |-- A: date (nullable = true)
 |-- B: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- C: string (nullable = true)

+----------+---+---+
|         A|  B|  C|
+----------+---+---+
|2022-01-04|  4|  D|
|2022-01-05|  5|  E|
|2022-01-06|  6|  F|
+----------+---+---+
```

Comment: `df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=df2.rdd,schema=df1.schema)` method wont work for converting `string` to `integer,long,date` types..!

Comment: I checked for the asked scenario and it works for me.

Comment: oh.. which version of spark you tried? I tried in `3.2.1` got error `Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'TypeError: field B: LongType can not accept object '2' in type <class 'str'>'`

Comment: I've tested in spark `3.3.0` as well as `3.1.2` worked in both versions. Even worked with the input dataframes that are part of your answer. :)

Comment: Weird, not sure if there are some issues with my setup.. Thanks for the test though :-)

Comment: both methods worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `dtypes`:

```py
df2.select([F.col(c).cast(t) for c, t in df1.dtypes])
```

---

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('1', '1.1')], ['col1', 'col2'])
df1.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- col2: string (nullable = true)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1.1)], ['col1', 'col2'])
df2.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- col2: double (nullable = true)

df2 = df2.select([F.col(c).cast(t) for c, t in df1.dtypes])
df2.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
```